# Return different value for condition in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have an ARRAYFORMULA that combines text with a number.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | textA | 0 |
| 2 | textB | 1 |
| 3 | textC | 2 |

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A3&" "&B1:B3)
```

But if the value in the B column is 0, I want the output cell to be empty like this:

|  | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | textB 1 | textC 2 |

What would be the best way to do this?

I have tried adding an if statement before the arrayformula that looked something like this

```
=IF(B1:B3=0)," ",ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A3&" "&B1:B3)
```

I assume that this is checking if the entire range equals 0, but I don't know if there is a way to check values per cell in the range.

I did not realize that ARRAYFORMULA would return a vertical list with a vertical range (although I probably should have figured that).

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither formula shown in your post would result in what you show in your second image. Your second formula seems it would have worked to produce a vertical result as desired *if* you had wrapped it in `ArrayFormula( )` as you did with the first.

Best I can tell from what you show, you want this in C1:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(IF(B1:B3=0,,A1:A3&" "&B1:B3)))`